# Best practices for using version-controlling on Cocoa projects

Tags: cocoa, svn, git, version-control

I recently started using Git as my version control system for some Cocoa projects I'm working on and wondered if there are best practices for working with version control systems on Cocoa projects.

There is the obvious "build" directory which I exclude from versioning as it's not important and can change quite a bit when debugging some code and then there are those .pbxuser and .perspectivev3 which change ever time I open the project in Xcode but I don't really know if they are "important" enough to be checked in.

Is there a commonly used configuration for excluding unimportant files?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my Mercurial `.hgignore` file, which is based on [Peter Hosey's](http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2008-03-20/hgignore-for-mac-os-x-applications).

```
syntax: glob

.DS_Store

*.swp
*~.nib

build

*.pbxuser
*.perspective
*.perspectivev3
*.mode1v3

*.pyc
```

Answer (score 1):

I never commit the ${LOGNAME}.* files as they're basically preferences information for the current user; the project sources, targets, dependencies and so on are in the project.pbxproj file. And as you mentioned in your question, the build directory (assuming you have the Place Build Products in: Project directory option set) is where the derived files live, so there's no need to check that in. You can always re-generate its contents from the source code.